# Proof of Doob Dynkin lemma when $X$ isn't assumed surjective

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

We consider the Euclidean space version of the Doob Dynkin lemma. In particular we first consider the real line, and the statement of the lemma becomes

> If $X,Y:\Omega\to \Bbb R$ are random variables, then $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X):=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)\}$ iff there exists Borel-measurable $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $Y=f(X)$.

Here's an outline for a proof in which $X$ *is* surjective, which hopefully may inspire some thoughts for the non-surjective case. The non-trivial direction is the existence of $f$. If we assume surjectivity of $X$ then the proof is easy. Let $Q_m^n:=[m/2^n,(m+1)/2^n)$ and $B_m^n\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ such that $Y^{-1}(Q_m^n)=X^{-1}(B_m^n)$. By surjectivity we would have that for any fixed $n$, $\uplus_mB_m^n = \Bbb R$ and hence we can define the following function:
$$f_n:\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto m/2^n\in\Bbb R,\quad x\in B_m^n.$$
And it is evident that $f_n$ is ever increasing at each $x\in\Bbb R$ and defining $f:=(\lim)f_n$ we can show $f(X)=Y$.

However, in the absence of the surjectivity of $X$, there seems to be no obvious way to "consistently" define the part of $B_m^n$ that is outside $X(\Omega)$ so that $\{B_m^{n+1}\}$ can be a refinement of $\{B_m^n\}$.

Is it possible to get around this difficulty? Also, I know there is a monotone class technique which can prove this result, but that's not what I want.

Cheers.

PS: it might be worth noting that when $X$ fails to be surjective, $f$ can't be uniquely determined (of course..)

Comment: How can you assume that the function that you are trying to prove what exists is surjective?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I can't. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I am not really following. Either you have a typo and what you are really assuming is that **X** is surjective or I am missing something...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez my point is: there is an easy proof, as outlined in the post, *if* we assume $X$ is surjective. Now what do we do without this assumption?

Comment: Ok. So you are assuming X is surjective. Then you have a typo that turns the beginning of your question weird, and you should fix it

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez no I'm not... it's just I demonstrate an easy proof *when* $X$ is surjective. For my question, though, I'm assuming $X$ is *not* surjective, and asking for help to modify my original proof to make it valid again or to give a new proof. The "assuming X is surjective" case is only for demonstration of my thoughts, and for people who may find ways to tweak it so that it still works for non-surjective $X$. If this part is not helpful to you, just ignore it.

Comment: The first sentence in bold reads "if we assume surjectivity of f"....

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it may have been those emphases that made my post look weird. I have edited.

Comment: No, what made it weird was that you wrote "if we assume the surjectivity of f" when you meant "if we assume the surjectivity of X". The fact that the sentence was in bold is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ahh! sorry I completely overlooked it. I thought you were confused at the surjective vs non-surjective thing but didn't realise there was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the following by a "monotone class technique", I will delete my answer. Otherwise, I think the following proof is nice:

We know (see e.g. [Measurable non-negative function is infinite linear combination of $\chi$-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849537/measurable-non-negative-function-is-infinite-linear-combination-of-chi-functi)) that if $f \geq 0$ is $\sigma (X ) $ measurable,  then $f = \sum_n c_n 1_{E_n} $ with $c_n \geq 0$ and $E_n \in \sigma (X) $. In particular, the series converges everywhere.

By definition of $\sigma (X) $, $E_n = X^{-1}(M_n) $ for suitable Borel sets $M_n $. Now, define $g_0 := \sum_n c_n 1_{M_n} $ and let $g := 1_{g_0 <\infty} \cdot g_0$ and note that $g $ is real valued and Borel measurable.  It is not hard to see $f = g_0 \circ X $ and then $f = g\circ X $, since $g_0 (X (\omega)) =f (\omega)<\infty $ for all $\omega$.

For the general case, split $f = f_+ - f_-$ and apply the preceding proof.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that your expressing a measurable function $f$ directly as linear sums is better than mine: which was essentially expressing the function $f$ as the *sup* of sequence of finite linear sums (so the "support sets" can vary and pointwise non-decreasing isn't guaranteed) rather than directly pointwise nonnegative linear sum with all support sets given as fixed.